# Dismissing Modal Presented ViewController Animation is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am simply trying to `present` a `ViewController` and `dismiss` it:

**Present:**

```
let completedWishesVC = WishlistViewController()
self.present(completedWishesVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Dismiss:**

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However it ends up looking like this:

[Screen-Video](https://gofile.io/d/faTNJ7)

What am I missing here? Let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: You might be setting a `UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve` somewhere

Comment: @aheze im not using storyboard here

Comment: & presenting works just fine. Only dismissing is not working correctly ...

Comment: Your dismiss code looks fine, the issue is probably somewhere else. Is `WishlistViewController` a navigation controller?

Comment: @aheze no it is a ‘viewController’.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have notice that you dismiss the menu action items before present your new VC. Just try to debug if that animation has any conflict or any pending state which might be conflicting during dismiss of your new VC.

Comment: @iDevAmit I've tried it withouth it, but that's not the issue..

Comment: @matt I tried it but can not get it done... I will work on it and update you as soon as I can